# Can I create a rEFInd entry for elementary OS that always uses the latest kernel?

Tags: release-freya, boot, dual-boot, refind

I run rEFInd on my laptop with Windows 10 and elementary OS. If I do not configure manual stanzas in rEFInd, it picks up the latest kernel version for elementary and displays: Windows 10, efi-grub and elementary OS, in that order. I want to change this order and display Windows 10, elementary OS and efi-grub. The reason I want to leave the grub entry is because it has the recovery option.

Currently, I achieve this using manual stanzas. But the problem in this case is that the code for elementary OS has the kernel number. Because of this, whenever I upgrade the kernel, rEFInd still runs the old kernel until I change it manually.

Any ideas for fixes? Or perhaps there is a .efi file for elementary OS that is compiled whenever a new kernel version is installed?

Comment: And as you would have it. There is another kernel upgrade on synaptic XD

Answer (score 1):

My refind config file is this:

```
resolution 1366 768
use_graphics_for linux,grub,windows
dont_scan_dirs /EFI/ubuntu,boot,/EFI/freebsd
default_selection "Elementary OS"
dont_scan_files /EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI

menuentry "Elementary OS" {
icon /EFI/refind/icons-backup/elementary.png
loader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
options "acpi_backlight=vendor resume=UUID=82a50ea8-2f1e-4307-b823-7cb3b03c74a1"
}

menuentry "FreeBSD" {
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_freebsd.png
    loader /EFI/freebsd/boot1.efi
}
```

And grub config is

```
#The important option is GRUB_DEFAULT set to saved for last used
#set to 0 for first entry/latest kernel
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=soft"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash iommu=soft usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Comment: I've got a similar setup, but I am assuming the /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi that you load for elementary os takes you to the grub menu. I am talking about a direct boot into elementary splashscreen with "loader /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic.efi.signed" and an initrd. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have the `grubx64.efi` file. How can I get it. I am using the EFI stub bootloader

Comment: I installed GRUB and now works

Comment: I added the rEFInd ext4 driver and removed GRUB. Better and faster